# Image of a map from R3 to R15 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I am trying to obtain the image of a map from R3 to R15. Let's suppose for the sake of simplicity that the map is:

F((x,y,z))=(x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z)

The domain of the map is the unit sphere. I know how to parametric this surface in order to obtain the image of the parametrization (the sphere). However, I'm at a loss on how to obtain its image under the map.

Obtaining the sphere is as simple as:

```
import numpy as np
#Pure states

pi = np.pi
cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0.0:pi:25j, 0.0:2.0*pi:25j]
x = sin(phi)*cos(theta)
y = sin(phi)*sin(theta)
z = cos(phi)
```

Any input will be highly appreciated. Maybe I should be using Mathematica instead?

To be more specific, I am trying to obtain 3D sections of the hypersurface created by the generalized Bloch vectors of a two-qubit system. The map comes from the restrictions applied to the system (for example, being a product state).

[Here's](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301152) an article with 2D sections of such objects.

Comment: Hi @IchVerlone. Could you be a little more specific? Eventually adding a link of the book/paper you want to reproduce? If you are working with differential grometry or math in general I suggest you to have a look at SageMath. You can use it online at  [cocalc.com/](https://cocalc.com/). It includes [Sage Manifold](https://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/) too.

Comment: for this map particularly, you can use `np.repeat`.

Comment: @rpanai I have edited my question. I guess Python isn't the right tool huh?

Comment: @QuangHoang That map is just an example.

Comment: @IchVerlore for general map, you would need to do a loop...

Comment: Yes Python is fine and [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) is built on top of Python. It just makes it easier if you are doing math.